# Changing date time format into another format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have an output "Wed Mar 1 00:00:00 2000". I want to convert this into the format '08/11/2019 05:45PM'. How to achieve this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like below

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed Mar 1 00:00:00 2000', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
```